# What does "in the saddle" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is a concrete example taken from a financial article:

> The ancient regime **is in the saddle**. I have to laugh whenever I hear Republicans ranting that Barack Obama is a “liberal” or a “socialist” or a communist

What does "in the saddle" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, *in the saddle* [means](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/saddle):

> 1. seated on a saddle
> 2. in a position of control

The article you quoted [goes on](http://www.thecenterlane.com/?tag=the-ancient-regime-is-in-the-saddle),

> I have to laugh whenever I hear Republicans ranting that Barack Obama is a “liberal” or a “socialist” or a communist.  Are you kidding me?  Obama is Bush 44.  He’s a bit more like the old man than the younger one.  **But look at who’s still running the economy: Bernanke. Geithner. Summers. Goldman Sachs. J.P. Morgan Chase. We’ve had the same establishment in charge since at least 1987, when Paul Volcker stood down as Fed chairman.  Change?  What “change”?**

So this is saying that the ancient regime is really "in the saddle", or in control. The names the article refers to--Bernanke, Geithner, Summers--are all men who have ostensibly been in control of the economy since the 1980s. So, even though Republicans say Obama is a "communist" or "socialist", in reality nothing has changed (in the author's opinion) because the same men are in power.

Answer (score 3):

As @simchona says, *in the saddle* means *in a position of control*.

It's a simple metaphor - particularly appropriate for Americans, taking into account the history of horseriding/cowboys/etc. There's also *holding the reins* - much the same metaphor and meaning.

A related metaphor based on cars rather than horses is *in the driving seat* [(British)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20driving%20seat,in%20the%20driver%27s%20seat&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) or *in the driver's seat* [(American)](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20driving%20seat,in%20the%20driver%27s%20seat&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3), which has rising usage whereas the equine ones are [falling](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hold%20the%20reins,holding%20the%20reins,in%20the%20saddle,in%20the%20driving%20seat&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3).

Comment: Actually, the American idiom is "in the DRIVER'S seat." Otherwise an upvote for you.

Comment: @Tom: Good point, thanks. I hadn't realised ther was such a marked US/UK difference over that one. Will edit it in.